# JAVA SE. Разница методов readObject() и readUnshared() класса ObjectInputStream?

Tags: java

Какая разница этих методов. Я читал документацию, но не понял что значит, как можно простыми словами описать разницу?! Или пример кода, демонстрирующий разницу использования. заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Если использовать readObject(), то в процессе повторного чтения Вы получите ссылку на прочитанный объект, а в случае использования readUnshared() Вы получите exception!